# Geoserver Docker Image With Latest GDAL

Tags: geoserver, gdal

Do you know where I can find a geoserver docker image that also contains the latest GDAL extension/version?

Comment: We are also searching for a dockerfile with preinstalled GDAL and MRSID-functionality. We tried editing this one: [thinkWhere/GeoServer-Docker](https://github.com/thinkWhere/GeoServer-Docker) But we've failed so far...

Answer (score 3):

I would check [this one](https://github.com/thinkWhere/GeoServer-Docker) which we have helped creating.

Comment: In the load-balanced, compose file, example, is each GeoServer instance running its own GeoWebCache?

Answer (score 0):

May be this container help you [winsent/geoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/winsent/geoserver/)